# Linkedin link share not getting title and description

Tags: php, facebook, linkedin-api

I am following instructions from linkedin from http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/46687/ft/eng

I am using following tags

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title of the article"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Description that will show in the preview"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/URL of the article" />
```

**Problem:**

My title, description and image are working perfectly on Facebook but LinkedIn not detecting these information.

Comment: Hi irfan, Did you get any silution ? i am getting same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's because Linkedin have an intern cache.
You just have to add your link and add after '?1'

Exemple:
    www.mywebsite.com?1

And the new meta desc is add automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution. working for me.

`window.open('https://linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + encodeURIComponent(link) + '&title= '+ title +'&summary=', 'twitterwindow', 'height=450, width=550, top='+(jQuery(window).height()/2 - 225) +', left='+jQuery(window).width()/2 +', toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');`

Comment: But i need to know about using meta tags. soif you have any solution please let me know.